# How to split an array of strings and convert to an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, split, nokogiri

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to split the following array and converting it into a format, so I can build an Active Record array of hashes.

My issue stems from writing an application that relies on Nokogiri to scrape information from the web.  The data in each row of a table I'm trying to extract, is jammed into a single `<td>` element. Every row has only one `<td>` element.

**EDIT:**
The first webpage contains a `<ul>` list of a few hundred items and a link to its details page. I iterate through each item, using the link to access the details page for parsing.  The table element I'm parsing below is from the details page. If you look at the output of `split_array`, I give the complete data of the first row (Level 1), then part of the second row (Level 2) to show that it is identical in structure but not in value.  Solving the problem for the first row, solves the problem for all 6 rows.

```
<td>
  Level 1
  <br>
    Attribute A: 24%
  <br>
    Attribute B: 14%
  <br>
    Attribute C: 15.5%
</td>
```

I managed to get the data in the following format as an array of arrays. I did this by splitting the long string with the following code:

```
row.xpath('tr').each_with_index do |td, j|
  split_array << td.text.squish.split('%')
end
```

Here is the partial output of `split_array`:

```
[["Level: 1 Attribute A: 24", "Attribute B: 14", "Attribute C: 15.5"],["Level: 2 Atribute A: 36", ..etc]..etc]
```

I need to:

1. get rid of the `Level: 1`, `Level: 2`... from the first element in each array
2. split the `Attribute` Name and the float values into their own field
3. convert those parts into an array of hashes that looks similar to this:

   ```
   [{:statistic => "Attribute A", :level_1 => 24.0, :level_2 =>36},{:statistic => "Attribute B", :level_1 => 14.0,:level_2 => 24},{:statistic => "Attribute C", :level_1 => 15.5, :level_2 => 34}]
   ```

I'm asking for code, pseudo code, or ideas  that will send me in the right direction to convert my array of arrays into the array of hashes I outlined above.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". I don't see a `Level: 2` from your sample HTML. Please make sure your input data matches your code and description; We can't get rid of something that isn't there.

Comment: If you scroll over, I showed only part of Level 2 for the sole purpose of illustrating it was identical in structure but not value. I edited my question to further explain.

Answer (score 0):

1) Rather than gulp in a `<td>` string with different kinds of information and then parse them, I suggest storing them in meaningful variables to begin with.  For example, store the level in 1 variable and the array of attribute statistics in another, getting them using the parsing facilities provided by Nokogiri.

2) Regarding these strings:

```
"Attribute B: 14"
```

Here is a script containing and illustrating a method that will parse them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def parse_attr_string(s)
  a = s.split
  name = a[1].gsub(':', '')
  value = a[2].gsub('%', '').to_f
  [name, value]
end

s = "Attribute B: 14"

name, value = parse_attr_string(s)

puts "Name: #{name}, Value: #{value}"  # Name: B, Value: 14.0
```

3) Regarding the reorganizing of the data, how about trying to figure it out and express it in pseudocode and then posting what you come up with if you have any problems with it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!  I will see where I can get with this, and If I have any further questions I'll post back here